# Belman Kalaba algorithm explained

Tags: graph-algorithm

Is there a difference between Belman-Ford and this?

Can someone explain how to implement this in order to find the longest path between to given nodes? 
I know the algorithm computes the shortest path between two nodes so if someone can explain how to implement that I can figure out how to modify it in order to give me the longest path.

Comment: As far as I know, Bellman-Kalaba paper is not about graphs at all. It's about Quasilinearization Method for Neumann Problems.

Comment: @Mysterion well, I got that as homework at graph-theory which is weird but this can explain why I'm totally lost.

Comment: Is the task ask you to implement Bellman-Kalaba algorithm? Or task is to find the longest path between given nodes?

Comment: Find the longest path between to given nodes using Bellman-Kalaba algorithm. If I could choose an algorithm things would be easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this in case someone else will have the same question in the future.

I found a python implementation (unfortunately it's not documented and I'm still playing around with it trying to fully understand it).

This computes the shortest path between one given node and all the other nodes in the graph.

```
from json.encoder import INFINITY
def BellmanKalaba(v,x,m):
    L=list()
    iteration=list()
    for j in range(len(v)):
        iteration.append(v[x][j])
    L.append(iteration)
    k=0
    while True:
        iteration=[0 for i in range(len(v))]
        for j in range(len(v)):
            minim=INFINITY
            for i in range(1,len(v)):
                a=L[len(L)-1][i]+v[i][j]
                if a < min:
                    minim=a
            iteration[j]=minim
        k+=1
        L.append(iteration)
        if iteration==L[len(L)-1]:
            return L
        if k==m:
            return 0
```

v is a matrix that represents a weighted graph,
x is the starting node,
m is the number of edges.

Now, this gets a bit weirder because L will actually contain 2 lists so the shortest path from x to y will be `min(L[0][y], L[1][y]).` 
I can't explain exactly how it works.
Also, this isn't working for any given graph.

It's a start, maybe now someone can jump in and help.